# Two dependency property have been changed instead of one

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, dependencies

I am creating user control based on Border and Label. I want to set Content property of UserControl to Label's Content property.

There is a WPF code of UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.TabButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Border x:Name="TabButtonBorder">
    <Label x:Name="TabButtonLabel" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="test content"/>
</Border>
```

And there is an class code:

```
    public partial class TabButton : UserControl
{

    public TabButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TabButtonLabel.DataContext = this;

        DependencyPropertyDescriptor contentDescriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ContentProperty, typeof(TabButton));
        contentDescriptor.AddValueChanged(TabButtonLabel, (s, e) => { ((Label)s).Content = Content; });
    }
}
```

It works in the way I want, but after content update foreground of the label changes to black, but as you see in the code it should be white. Why is it that?

Comment: This looks strange. Why don't you have the usual ContentPresenter in a ControlTemplate? Why is this a UserControl at all, instead of e.g. a derived Label?

Comment: Because I also have to use Border to style the control. Generally I want to create style in resource dictionary for this control.

Comment: That would of course be possible with the standard ways of using Styles and Templates. Your approach seems broken.

Comment: I'd suggest you start with a control derived from Label, with a standard default Style in Themes/Generic.xaml, where it declares a ControlTemplate with a ContentPresenter inside a Border.

Comment: Even simpler, do not create a derived control class at all. Just declare appropriate Styles and ControlTemplates, e.g. for the Label class. See [Control authoring overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but a UserControl that always uses a `Label` inside a `Border` to visualize its `Content` should do this by means of its `ControlTemplate`. No additional code behind would be required.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.TabButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <Border>
                <Label Foreground="White" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```